# Cancel the modification of an environment by `\tcolorboxenvironment`

Tags: tcolorbox

The command `\tcolorboxenvironment` can modify an environment to change the way it appears and add around it some graphical elements (background color, etc.)

From the doc:

```
\newenvironment{myitemize}
{\begin{itemize}}
{\end{itemize}}

\tcolorboxenvironment{myitemize}{blanker, 
                                 before skip=6pt,
                                 after skip=6pt, 
                                 borderline west={3mm}{0pt}{red}}
```

I wonder if it is possible to cancel such an alteration of the `myitemize` environment.

My goal is to have an environment that can be customised when some "variables" are put to "True" and otherwise left in their "original" form.
Presently, I want to be able to put a background color to the environment, depending on the value of some "variables".

Comment: Could you specify your "variables"? Are that some `\newif`s?

Comment: The variables are defined as `\global\def\myVariable{1}` or `0`.

Comment: Why do you try to create an own boolean logic? But whether you test an `\ifnum` or use a `\newif` or something similar should not matter that much.

Comment: I don't try to create my own boolean logic. I just try to code within LaTeX, and I admit that my code might be stupid/ugly (I'm sure it is). Sorry, I'm more used to other langages (like Python or C, where I can just do `x = True` for instance...)

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `\tcolorboxenvironment` is

```
\newcommand{\tcolorboxenvironment}[2]{%
  \AddToHook{env/#1/before}{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[savedelimiter={#1},#2,wrap@environment,%
      code={\def\tcb@end@tcolorboxenvironment{\end{tcolorbox}}}]%
  }%
  \AddToHook{env/#1/after}{%
    \tcb@end@tcolorboxenvironment%
  }%
}
```

So applying `\RemoveFromHook` before and after the environment should do the trick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{myitemize}
{\begin{itemize}}
{\end{itemize}}

\tcolorboxenvironment{myitemize}{blanker, 
                                 before skip=6pt,
                                 after skip=6pt, 
                                 borderline west={3mm}{0pt}{red}}
\begin{document}

\begin{myitemize}
\item text
\item more text
\end{myitemize}

\RemoveFromHook{env/myitemize/before}
\RemoveFromHook{env/myitemize/after}

\begin{myitemize}
\item text
\item more text
\end{myitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For convenience you can also define a command that removes the hooks:

```
\newcommand{\untcolorboxenvironment}[1]{
    \RemoveFromHook{env/#1/before}
    \RemoveFromHook{env/#1/after}
    }
```

Then replace the `\RemoveFromHook`'s in the document above with `\untcolorboxenvironment{myitemize}`.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple suggestion: use the variables outside and simply include a check into the environment (could be more complex with etoolbox etc.):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myitemizeenv}{blanker, 
                                 before skip=6pt,
                                 after skip=6pt, 
                                 borderline west={3mm}{0pt}{red}}

\newif\ifstyleme
\newenvironment{myitemize}{%
    \ifstyleme\begin{myitemizeenv}\fi%
    \begin{itemize}
}{%
    \end{itemize}%
    \ifstyleme\end{myitemizeenv}\fi%
}

\begin{document} 

\begin{myitemize}
    \item Item
    \item Item 2
\end{myitemize}

\stylemetrue

\begin{myitemize}
    \item Item
    \item Item 2
\end{myitemize}

\stylemefalse

\begin{myitemize}
    \item Item
    \item Item 2
\end{myitemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know about this syntax `\newif\if#something#`