# \RemoveFromHook not working as expected if code placed in package file

Tags: tcolorbox, hooks, lthooks

In my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/680688/208544), something occurred that I don't understand about the hook system. If the code that adds a hook is directly in the main tex file (`\tcolorboxenvironment` in this example), it works as I expect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{myitemize}
{\begin{itemize}}
{\end{itemize}}

\tcolorboxenvironment{myitemize}{blanker, 
                                 before skip=6pt,
                                 after skip=6pt, 
                                 borderline west={3mm}{0pt}{red}}
\begin{document}

\begin{myitemize}
\item text
\item more text
\end{myitemize}

\RemoveFromHook{env/myitemize/before}
\RemoveFromHook{env/myitemize/after}

\begin{myitemize}
\item text
\item more text
\end{myitemize}

\end{document}
```

produces one list with a red border, one without. Note the definition of `\tcolorboxenvironment`:

```
\newcommand{\tcolorboxenvironment}[2]{%
  \AddToHook{env/#1/before}{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[savedelimiter={#1},#2,wrap@environment,%
      code={\def\tcb@end@tcolorboxenvironment{\end{tcolorbox}}}]%
  }%
  \AddToHook{env/#1/after}{%
    \tcb@end@tcolorboxenvironment%
  }%
}
```

However if I move this code into `mytest.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mytest}

\RequirePackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{myitemize}
{\begin{itemize}}
{\end{itemize}}

\tcolorboxenvironment{myitemize}{blanker, 
                                 before skip=6pt,
                                 after skip=6pt, 
                                 borderline west={3mm}{0pt}{red}}
```

then try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mytest}

\begin{document}

\begin{myitemize}
\item text
\item more text
\end{myitemize}

\RemoveFromHook{env/myitemize/before}
\RemoveFromHook{env/myitemize/after}

\begin{myitemize}
\item text
\item more text
\end{myitemize}

\end{document}
```

I get both lists having a red border. What difference should it make if the code is in a package or directly in the preamble?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You need the package label as the default label is `mytest` inside the package, but `top-level` outside.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mytest}

\begin{document}

\begin{myitemize}
\item text
\item more text
\end{myitemize}

\RemoveFromHook{env/myitemize/before}[mytest]
\RemoveFromHook{env/myitemize/after}[mytest]

\begin{myitemize}
\item text
\item more text
\end{myitemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah! I should really read the documentation :-)