# Understanding \RemoveFromHook with label

Tags: tcolorbox, lthooks

I've realized my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452498/208544) about removing the effect of `\tcolorboxenvironment` is not ideal because it removes all content from the hooks `env/<envname>/before` and `env/<envname>/after`, not just the code set by tcolorbox. Here's the example from my answer that removes all code added to the hooks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{myitemize}{\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}

\tcolorboxenvironment{myitemize}{
    blanker, 
    before skip=6pt,
    after skip=6pt, 
    borderline west={3mm}{0pt}{red}
    }
                                 
\AddToHook{env/myitemize/after}{some code}

\newcommand{\untcolorboxenvironment}[1]{
    \RemoveFromHook{env/#1/before}
    \RemoveFromHook{env/#1/after}
    }
    
\begin{document}

\begin{myitemize}
\item text
\item more text
\end{myitemize}

\untcolorboxenvironment{myitemize}

\begin{myitemize}
\item text
\item more text
\end{myitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: bad]

One can imagine a situation where the user or other packages add to these hooks so `\untcolorboxenvironment` should only remove the code added by tcolorbox. From `lthooks-doc`, it would seem the label for this code is `tcolorbox` since in `tcolorbox.sty` no label is given and it should default to the package name. However defining `\untcolorboxenvironment` as

```
\newcommand{\untcolorboxenvironment}[1]{
    \RemoveFromHook{env/#1/before}[tcolorbox]
    \RemoveFromHook{env/#1/after}[tcolorbox]
    }
```

produces a warning saying this chunk does not exist for this hook. What is the correct way to remove just the code added by tcolorbox?

Comment: Use \ShowHook to find out which chunks are there and how they are named.

Comment: I don't think `tcolorbox` adds code to the environment using a hook...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik It does. You can see the definition of `\tcolorboxenvironment` in (my answer to) the linked question

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. I see now that even though `\tcolorboxenvironment` is defined in `tcolorbox.sty`, the actual adding to the hooks occurs in the document. So I guess there's no good answer then since by default the hooks are declared top-level, unless one alters the definition of `\tcolorboxenvironment`

Comment: @mbert Oh, I see.  You can use `\PushDefaultHookLabel{tcolorbox}` before `\tcolorboxenvironment` and `\PopDefaultHookLabel` after, then the code is added under the `tcolorbox` label

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Nice! Just curious, why does that change the position of `some code`? Does changing the label also change the execution order (or something else)? Also feel free to add as answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot remove a `tcolorbox` label because there is none.  Using `\ShowHook{env/myitemize/after}` tells you that (note that the "Code chunks" part is empty):

```
-> The generic hook 'env/myitemize/after':
> Code chunks:
>     ---
> Document-level (top-level) code (executed first):
>     -> \tcb@end@tcolorboxenvironment some code
> Extra code for next invocation:
>     ---
> Rules:
>     ---
> Execution order (after reversal):
>     ---.
<recently read> }

l.25 \ShowHook{env/myitemize/after}

?
```

Instead, the `tcolorbox` code is added in the `top-level` chunk, along with your `some code`.  This happens because the `\tcolorboxenvironment` *is* executed at top-level, so the code is added there.

To ensure the code is in a proper label, you can do:

```latex
\PushDefaultHookLabel{tcolorbox}
  \tcolorboxenvironment{myitemize}{ ... }
\PopDefaultHookLabel
```

then, all the code added to a hook will be labeled `tcolorbox` (unless explicitly told otherwise).  After doing that, `\ShowHook` then says (note now that "Code chunks" contains the `tcolorbox` label):

```
-> The generic hook 'env/myitemize/after':
> Code chunks:
>     tcolorbox -> \tcb@end@tcolorboxenvironment
> Document-level (top-level) code (executed first):
>     -> some code
> Extra code for next invocation:
>     ---
> Rules:
>     ---
> Execution order (after reversal):
>     tcolorbox.
<recently read> }

l.25 \ShowHook{env/myitemize/after}

?
```

---

Additionally, you will note that the `top-level` section is introduced as "`Document-level (top-level) code (executed first)`", because this is a reversed hook (`env/.../after` hooks are reversed), so the `top-level` code is executed before the code labeled `tcolorbox`.

To reverse the execution order, you have to put your top-level code in a label, then you can order them, like this:

```
\AddToHook{env/myitemize/after}[mycode]{some code}
\DeclareHookRule{env/myitemize/after}{mycode}{after}{tcolorbox}
```

then, `\ShowHook` will tell you the execution order you want:

```latex
-> The generic hook 'env/myitemize/after':
> Code chunks:
>     tcolorbox -> \tcb@end@tcolorboxenvironment
>     mycode -> some code
> Document-level (top-level) code (executed first):
>     ---
> Extra code for next invocation:
>     ---
> Rules:
>     tcolorbox|mycode with relation <
> Execution order (after reversal and applying rules):
>     tcolorbox, mycode.
<recently read> }

l.26 \ShowHook{env/myitemize/after}

?
```

---

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{myitemize}{\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}

\PushDefaultHookLabel{tcolorbox}
\tcolorboxenvironment{myitemize}{
    blanker, 
    before skip=6pt,
    after skip=6pt, 
    borderline west={3mm}{0pt}{red}
    }
\PopDefaultHookLabel

\AddToHook{env/myitemize/after}[mycode]{some code}
\DeclareHookRule{env/myitemize/after}{mycode}{after}{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\untcolorboxenvironment}[1]{%
    \RemoveFromHook{env/#1/before}[tcolorbox]%
    \RemoveFromHook{env/#1/after}[tcolorbox]%
    }

\begin{document}

\ShowHook{env/myitemize/after}

\begin{myitemize}
\item text
\item more text
\end{myitemize}

\untcolorboxenvironment{myitemize}

\begin{myitemize}
\item text
\item more text
\end{myitemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think your `\RemoveFromHook`'s are missing `[tcolorbox]`, or am I missing something? Either way, thanks for the excellent explanation

Comment: @mbert Ah, yes, thanks.  I just copied from your question and forgot to change